# I register and enqueue stylesheet but nothing is rendered

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I'm told it's very important to register and enqueue styles and scripts in WordPress even though it's a real pain.

I had no problem with the scripts however when I try the styles, WordPress shows nothing in the code for stylesheets. I'd like to get in the habit of building my themes the correct way so I'd like to learn how this is done, but I can't understand why my css is not added to the code when the scripts are added. See code to functions file below:

```
<?php

function alpha_scripts(){

  $script = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/';

  wp_register_script('bootstrap-js', $script . 'bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'', false);

  //wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');
}

function alpha_styles(){

  $style = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/styles/';

    wp_register_style('bootstrap-css', $style . 'bootstrap.min.css','','', 'screen');
    wp_register_style('alpha-css', $style . 'alpha.css','','', 'screen');

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css');
    wp_enqueue_style('alpha-css');
}

function alpha_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
      'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' )
    )
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alpha_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_styles', 'alpha_styles');
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'alpha_menus');

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried using different references for the url, like `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` but as I suspected those two made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing well - just one thing you need to change, and I reckon it's a totally reasonable mistake to make:

This:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_styles', 'alpha_styles');
```

needs to become

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alpha_styles');
```

Why `scripts`? Because there is no Wordpress action called `wp_enqueue_styles`. Although the *functions* are named `wp_register_style` & `wp_enqueue_style`, you still need to hook them to the multi-purpose `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Yes, WP core should probably just add a second action to save this issue from occuring... :)

Although it can be a pain at first, once you get your head around how the enqueues work, it'll save you a lot of time in future. There's several benefits: dependencies can be managed easily; your scripts & styles will function across multiple headers and footers if you have them; and plugins that hook into scripts & styles (eg. to concatenate/minify them) can do their job.

Comment: Thanks Tim Malone! I actually just stumbled onto this solution except I used wp_print_styles for the hook instead of the enqueue scripts one. Is this an incorrect way of doing that? If it is correct then I'll still give you the answer check if you edit your answer for the wp_print_styles. If it's not correct could you please explain why not to use wp_print_styles action hook? Thanks again man!

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles

Comment: Yeah using `wp_print_styles` is incorrect unfortunately! :) See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/ for a good explanation straight from the horse's mouth.